# Focus prevents onclick

Tags: android

Some element is stealing the focus, and the clicks on my listview don't register.
Can someone suggest a way to find which?

Here is how the app works:

Activity > inner custom View > onTouch > AlertDialog.builder.setView(custom ListView)

I mistakenly thought I needed two choices, and used with total success the same setup, using .setPositiveButton and .setNegativeButton on the builder before. But I need more choices, therefore a ListView.

Here are the relevant lines from the ListView:

```
final ListView lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) { convertView = new TextView(GameActivity.this); }
    ((TextView)convertView).setText((String)getItem(position));
    return convertView;
  }
  public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
  public String getItem(int position) { return names[position]; }
  public int getCount() { return names.length; }
});                     
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  ///////Nothing happens, never called
  }
});
```

I read twenty or thirty stack overflow posts, it almost always has something to do with a view stealing the focus.
Which view is stealing the focus, how can I debug this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: If `convertView` is simply a TextView like you defined above, then something else is awry... What are you trying to do in `onItemClick()` and how do you know it is not called?

Comment: Oh! it works... but the dialog stays open. I suppose I spent two hours reading stackoverflow for no other reason that I am dumb. But thanks for answering, that tipped me in the right direction!

Comment: "I suppose I spent two hours reading stackoverflow for no other reason that I am dumb." Hopefully you learned a few tricks while researching so it was not time wasted. But simply call `dialog.dismiss()` in `onItemClick()` to close it.

Comment: yeah, as soon as thanks to you I noticed it worked, I added the dismiss call, and am now one happy cat, thanks Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in Sam's comment: it simply worked, and I wasn't dismiss()ing the dialog.